# R Unlist list and assign element position

Tags: r, list, type-conversion, data.table

I've got a List of which I show element 999.

[image]

I need to convert it into a data.table in which the element number is assigned as follows:

[image]

Tried different possible solutions but nothing seems to be working properly.

Comment: Tried *what* "different possible solutions"?

Comment: for example as.data.table(t(x)) where x is my list

Comment: That [[999]] element looks like a data.table would be printed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `do.call('rbind', ...)` to get a dataframe from your list, and `rep()` on the list's indices with the `times` argument set to `sapply(l, nrow)` (where `l` is the name of your list) to get the desired element numbers:

```r
# Make an example list
l <- list(data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6), data.frame(a = 7:8, b = 8:9))
l
#> [[1]]
#>   a b
#> 1 1 4
#> 2 2 5
#> 3 3 6
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   a b
#> 1 7 8
#> 2 8 9
# Get a dataframe from it
df <- do.call('rbind', l)
# Add the element numbers by repeating the indices of the list,
# each as many times as the number of rows in that element's dataframe
df$element_number <- rep(seq_along(l), times = sapply(l, nrow))
df
#>   a b element_number
#> 1 1 4              1
#> 2 2 5              1
#> 3 3 6              1
#> 4 7 8              2
#> 5 8 9              2
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This works even better:

```
df <- rbindlist(l, fill = TRUE, use.names = TRUE, idcol = "element_number")
```

Comment: Fyi, `rbindlist` has a dedicated argument for this: `rbindlist(..., idcol="element_number")`